# insert data from staging table to 2 tables by reusing postgres index or bigserial

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-10

I have 3 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE stage
(
  a1 text,
  b2 text,
  c3 text,
  d4 text,
  e5 text
);

CREATE TABLE main
(
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  a1 text,
  b2 text,
  c3 text
);

CREATE TABLE secondary (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  mainid bigint,
  d4 text,
  e5 text,
  CONSTRAINT secondary_fkey FOREIGN KEY(mainid) REFERENCES main(id)
);
```

I want to insert data from `stage` into `main` and `secondary` at once but I'm not quite sure how to do that by reusing generated bigserial in `main`. I'm trying a `with query` but I'm getting more rows (exponentially) in `secondary` than expected.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=086b3fe5d5ee93efea829a066ebd222a)

```
WITH tmp AS (
  INSERT INTO
    main (a1, b2, c3)
  SELECT
    a1,
    b2,
    c3
  FROM
    stage RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO
  secondary (mainid, d4, e5)
SELECT
  tmp.id,
  stage.d4,
  stage.e5
FROM
  tmp,
  stage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the cross join you create in the final `INSERT` statement with the `FROM tmp, stage;`. If you have 10 rows in the stage table, this will generate 100 rows rathe than the 10 you want.

If `(a1, b2, c3)` uniquely identity a row in `stage` you could use them for a proper join condition:

```
WITH tmp AS (
  INSERT INTO main (a1, b2, c3)
  SELECT a1, b2, c3
  FROM stage 
  RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO secondary (mainid, d4, e5)
SELECT tmp.id,
       stage.d4,
       stage.e5
FROM tmp 
  JOIN stage 
    on tmp.a1 = stage.a1 
   and tmp.b2 = stage.b2 
   and tmp.c3 = stage.c3;
```

If that is not feasible (because there are duplicates) you can generate the new IDs for the `main` table *before* the insert using `nextval()`

```
with stage_with_mainid as (
  select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('main', 'id')) as mainid,
         a1, b2, c3, d4, e5
  from stage       
), insert_main as (
  insert into main (id, a1, b2, c3) --<< this provides the generated new ID explictely
  select mainid, a1, b2, c3
  from stage_with_mainid
)
insert into secondary (mainid, d4, e5)
select mainid, d4, e5
from stage_with_mainid;
```